# Jasper Reports path issues, cannot find .jasper files when running on App server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jasper-reports

When running in Tomcat (out of Eclipse w/debugger), how are you supposed to get a .jasper file (say as an InputStream) for `JasperFillManager.fillReport()` to use?  Currently our .jasper files are within `/WEB-INF/jasper`.

I need a solution that doesn't break based on where you happen to be running the report from. If it's being debugged while running Tomcat from Eclipse, `System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns `C:/Eclipse ...` but obviously, that path will be different when it's deployed to a server.

How do you get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working running from tomcat/eclipse by changing the Tomcat launch configuration working directory from within Eclipse. This lets you just pass a relative path to fillReport() in the Java code.  But I've yet to try testing from within websphere... (something tells me I'll be cursing IBM again soon).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not plan to replace the .jasper file after it was created then you could use the resources and [getResourcesAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the application object (assuming you're using JSPs rather than servlets - I've not been using them)

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(application.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/jasper")+"/report.jasper"));
```

Comment: Not JSPs, this integrates with a Flex application